# jQuery - .trigger() doesn't work after .load() 

Tags: jquery, ajax, triggers, load

This is my code:

```
function refresh () {   
    sub_tab=$("#hid").val();
    $("#content").load(cur_tab+'.php',function () {
        alert(sub_tab);
        $("#pd").trigger('click');
    });     
}
```

The line `$("#pd").trigger('click');` doesn't seem to work. However, if I execute this line as a standalone operation (without `load`), it works.
`#pd` is a `<div>` which is being loaded into the page which contains the above script.
Any ideas?

#pd is *inside* another PHP page which is loaded into #content
. Now when i click #pd, it works fine, just that , the trigger event does not seem to work, when i reload the PHP file into #content

Comment: @ianbarker: This here is a different `load` method: http://api.jquery.com/load/. It loads the response from calling `cur_tab+'.php'` into `#content`.

Comment: @ianbarker: there are two distinct `.load()` methods in jQuery.

Comment: @Anant: does the `alert` pop up ?

Comment: @jAndy : Yes it does.I put it there in the first place, just to check if the request was going through correctly

Comment: @Anant: then the other question is important -> does #content contain #pd. In that case it overwrites all bound event handlers.

Comment: yes it does. Hmm, thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

If the `click` event is bound to `#pd`, and `#pd` is inside of `#content`, you lose the binding every time you reload the content, because `#pd` is being destroyed and recreated.

Try using [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to bind the event - it plays much more nicely with Ajax calls and dynamic DOM:

```
$("#content").delegate("#pd", "click", function(){
    // click event
});
```

Later, when you will call `$("#pd").trigger('click');`, you should see the expected results.

Comment: hmm, thanks., though i'm still having problems, this seems to render my code following this function ,passive

Comment: @Anant - No need to be sorry, but if you want to get a good answer, you need to edit the question - explain exactly what you're doing, and how it "doesn't work". The answer is based on many *assumptions* - it's an educated guess.